# Чудеса с svg иконками

Tags: svg

Второй день бьюсь с этими svg и пока безрезультатно. Казалось бы чего проще, взять из PSD макета в фотошопе векторную иконку, сохранить как svg, вставить в верстку и готово. Но не тут то было. Иконки упорно не хотят отображаться через `background-image`. Через `img` работают только в Firefox и IE, а в Chrome и Opera не работают. Причем, если открывать саму иконку через любой браузер, то они ее прекрасно отображают. Еще был интересный момент, что если вставить скопированный код иконки между тегами, которым задан `background` с `svg`, то иконки отобразятся. Удалить код, перезагрузиться - и опять ничего не показывает. Пожалуйста, кто знает в чем тут дело, помогите!

Часть кода (через img):

```
<li><img src="images/advantages-1.svg" alt="">Собственная производственная база</li>
```

(через background):

```
& li {
    font-size: 1.14rem;
    list-style: none;
    padding: 9px 0 9px 40px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: 0 50%;
    background-size: 30px 30px;

    & img{
        opacity: 1;
    }

    &:nth-child(1) {
        background-image: url("/images/advantages-1.svg");
    }
}
```

код иконки:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="23" height="27" viewBox="0 0 23 27">
    <defs>
      <style>
        .cls-1 {
          opacity: 0.33;
        }
      </style>
  </defs>
  <image id="Vector_Smart_Object" data-name="Vector Smart Object" class="cls-1" width="23" height="27" xlink:href="data:img/png;base64,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"/>
</svg>
```

Comment: открой svg ты мог вытянуть в формате base64 и отображение через svg не будет, посмотри код svg <image xlink:href="data:img/png;base64, если так начинается, то не svg

Comment: Да есть base64. Это можно исправить? Если нельзя, то может Вы знаете как вытягивать из Rhotoshop СС без этого base64?

Comment: вот и естественно никак оно отображать не будет, смотря как вам предоставили дизайн и не желательно переделывать в смарт обьект, а сразу тянуть чистым и тянуть из Photoshop CC либо же уговорить дизанера предоставить вам сразу иконки в таком формате

Comment: Спасибо! Непонятно только зачем растр упаковали как смарт. Всю голову себе поломал.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Фотошоп сохранил вам иконку в svg-файл, но содержащую внутри себя png-картинку в base64 формате.

Быстрое решение - поставить на фон требуемого вам блока этот base64-код, вот так:

```
& :nth-child(1) {
    background-image: url("data:img/png;base64,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");
}
```

А svg-файл вам не понадобится.

Возможно вам имеет смысл связаться с автором PSD-макета и попросить его скинуть вам png-файлы иконок, которые он вставлял в макет. Это будет проще, чем вырезать из макета смарт-объекты и вставлять base64 в стили.

---

Также, когда вы устанавливаете фон блока (неважно, сплошной цвет, градиент или изображение) - вы влияете лишь на фон блока, но не на его размеры. И если размеры блока явно не заданы - вы получаете блок размером `0px 0px`, который оказывается не виден.

Задайте размеры блока явно через `height` и `width`, взяв значения из размеров svg в вашем PSD макете.

Comment: Разумеется, все подобные манипуляции с размерами и цветом я уже делал. К сожалению не помогло.

Comment: Тогда пожалуйста, дополните ваш вопрос стилями, которые вы присваиваете блоку помимо `background-image`.

Comment: & li {
        font-size: 1.14rem;
        list-style: none;
        padding: 9px 0 9px 40px;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-position: 0 50%;
        background-size: 30px 30px;
        & img{
            opacity: 1;
        }
        &:nth-child(1) {
            background-image: url("/images/advantages-1.svg");
        }

Comment: В комментариях теряется форматирование кода. Дополните **вопрос**. А код в комментариях выше - удалите.

Comment: Извините, пока не разобрался как правильно код вставлять.

Comment: @Евгений, дополнил ответ по вашей проблеме. Когда прочтете - давайте почистим комментарии к моему ответу, они перестали нести пользу. Вы удалите свои, и я удалю свои.

Comment: base64 предоставлен для мелких деталей на странице, а лить фон полностью не желательно, он дает возможность не делать лишние http запросы на разные мелочи

Comment: Виталий, в комментариях к моему вопросу в конце появляется значок удаления, а здесь пока не нашел как удалить мои комменты.

Comment: Спасибо! Мне проще будет из ФШ пересохранить как пнг. Я просто был уверен, что это векторная иконка, вот и мучился.

Answer (score 1):

1. Проверить наличие `xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"` у тега `svg`.
2. Проверить наличие `<?xml version="1.0"?>` в начале файла.

> ```
> <svg xmlns="w3.org/2000/svg"; xmlns:xlink="w3.org/1999/xlink"; width="23" height="27" viewBox="0 0 23 27"> <defs> <style> .cls-1 { opacity: 0.33; } </style> </defs>
> ```

Тут какой-то мусор в атрибутах, плюс пара лишних. Попробуй так:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="0 0 23 27"><defs>
```

Comment: Первая строчка есть, вот второй вроде не нашел.

Comment: <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="23" height="27" viewBox="0 0 23 27">
  <defs>
    <style>
      .cls-1 {
        opacity: 0.33;
      }
    </style>
  </defs>

Comment: Правки не помогают.

Comment: @Евгений я же тебе выше написал, что нужно делать: никакие правки в этом ответе не помогут, если ты вытащил base64

Comment: @LieutenantJimDangle, использовать base64 для текстовых данных - это извращение.